# Сравнить даты js

Tags: javascript, время

Всем привет. Есть строка с записью даты:

```
"Sun, 06 Aug 2017 13:05:14 +0300"
```

Как из нее получить дату для сравнения с текущим временем?

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать примерно так :

```js
var date1 = +new Date('Sun, 06 Aug 2017 13:05:14 +0300');
var dateNow = +new Date();

console.log(dateNow > date1);

var diff = new Date(dateNow - date1);
console.log('diff = ' + +diff + ' ms.');
```

Унарным плюсом приводим даты к числам и их спокойно сравниваем, отнимаем, додаем, умножаем, вобщем делаем что угодно, а потом с результата формируем новую дату и чтото с ней делаем, количество дней к примеру можно пощитать примерно так :

```
Math.round(+diff/(1000*60*60*24));
```

Comment: даты и так прекрасно сравниваются и отнимаются, не надо их к числам приводить, ну и разница дат - это уже количество миллисекунд нет нужды делать `new Date` для нее

Comment: @Grundy с разницей я конечно тупанул, спс :) но лично мне все же удобней работать с числами нежели с датами :)

Comment: ©"...получить дату для сравнения с текущим временем..." - если вам необходимо получить именно время [13:05:14] из данной строки и сравнить со временем текущим - то это одно решение. Если текущую дату целиком - то это другое решение, которое вам уже предложили. Пожалуйста пишите правильно..